# Best way host own sso Oauth2 service for web / native applications using Spring

Tags: android, ios, spring, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I want:

- central oauth2 server which will hold all user accounts and will provide platform for user account management
- multiple services which will connect to central oauth2 server to verify user. Each service will have Web and mobile applications (iOS, Android)

I followed [spring-boot-oauth tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) and have client that connects to server for credentials using redirect. This works fine for browsers, but I wish to be able to login directly in native apps. I think using grant_type=password should solve the problem, but I can not find good description how to approach this.

1. Should I send token request directly to central server for refresh token, or should I proxy it through each application service?
2. Is there any way to check on native app if user is already logged in central server from device, or do I always need to send login/password? I'm aware that I could [develop separate application to which I will redirect user for verification](https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/#mobile-apps), but for user-experience and time-efficient reasons I would like to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking of native mobile apps on Android and iOS, then I would recommend looking at these libraries...

https://openid.github.io/AppAuth-iOS/

https://openid.github.io/AppAuth-Android/

These libraries allow you to use implicit or code authorization flows, avoiding the grant_type=password flow which makes it more difficult to get single sign on.